# Cannot see files from DSM I made with Transmission on NFS share on Synology NAS

Tags: nfs

I installed Tranmission on my Pi3 today, mainly following this post: [Permission problems with Transmission](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91611/permission-problems-with-transmission). I finally got it working I thought, but now I ran into something weird.

From the Pi3 side everything seems to be working. Downloads initiate and are written and moved arround, even my sabnzbd installation downloaded a test file and transfered it to the 'completed' directory:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/synology/TORRENTS $ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 pi pi 4096 Oct 20 17:47  .
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 Oct 20 13:23  ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Oct 20 17:47  INCOMPLETE
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Oct 20 14:30 'BlaBlaBla.720p.WEB-DL.EN-SUB.x264'
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Oct 20 17:58  test_download_100MB
```

But when I check the share in Windows or in the Synology file browser none of the downloaded files are there.

Can somebody enlighten me on what is happening here and how I can make these files visible for Windows and Synology?

I've just gotten my feet wet when it comes to Linux, so please don't be too concise and elaborate. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add some software to Windows in order for it to read NFS.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro supports NFS if you enable it. Which Windows version do you have

Comment: @goldilocks Indeed, but I still don't understand why the the DSM file browser cannot see the files. DSM understands NFS out of the box, right?. It's the other way arround too: files and folders created from my Windows PC or from the DSM file browser are not visible to the Pi3. I can even make a folder called 'TORRENT' on the PI3 and make a folder 'TORRENT' in the DSM file browser in the same share without getting a conflict.

Comment: Could it be because DSM has no clue as to who user  ```pi:pi``` is? (Sorry if this sounds stupid, am learning as I go here and I'am just getting started)

Comment: I'm actually not a Windows user, so I can't comment further on all that.  The actual storage here is attached to the Pi, right?  So you can check locally what is really in the NFS exported directory.  Chances are it is the same view as from the Pi, and the stuff you are supposedly putting in it from the Windows side isn't there at all.  If you can reboot the Windows machine and it is still there from that end, then whatever it supposed to be the NFS mount obviously isn't, it's stored on the Windows machine somewhere.  I would guess instead it isn't anywhere, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @goldilocks Man oh man, finally found what went wrong. I made an error in the path of the mount target, so the files never reached the share, they were just somewhere on the sdcard of the Pi. When I corrected the error, I got a new NFS error. Couldn't solve that one, so had another go as to why my CIFS entry in ```/etc/fstab``` worked fine in the CLI, but continued to have Permission Denied error in Transmission. Turns out I had ```vers=3.0``` specified, which aparently Transmission did not like at all. When I removed that everything worked just fine. Anyway, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can I close a question? Or how do I handle this, pretty new to StackExchange so no clue.

Comment: Please just write an answer. That will finish the question and show others that is has a solution. Seems you can just move your comment with the solution into the answer field. It is nothing wrong with answering the own question.

Comment: *"they were just somewhere on the sdcard of the Pi"* -> Pretty sure you mean not in the mount directory, but if you mean it was the storage mounted on the wrong place, note that you can mount stuff on a directory with content -- what happens then is you can't access that content until you remove the mount.  So if you only ever use the directory as a mount, it's easy to at one point copy stuff into the dir by mistake when nothing is mounted, then not notice it for months because normally something *is* always mounted there.  Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

Finally found what went wrong. I made an error in the path of the mount target, so the files never reached the share, they were just somewhere on the sdcard of the Pi. But when I corrected the error, I got a new NFS error. Couldn't solve that one, so had another go as to why my CIFS entry in `/etc/fstab` worked fine in the CLI, but continued to have Permission Denied error in Transmission. Turns out I had the `vers=3.0` option specified, which aparently Transmission did not like at all. When I removed that everything worked just fine.